# Difference between passing a string to a function versus calling the function with a default parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a small application that increments a counter when a picture of a cat is clicked. When I set the function with default parameters, it works. However, when I pass it a string to substitute in the function, it does not. What is the difference between these two scripts?

The first script, which does not pass a string to the catClick function:

```
'use strict';

function CatCount (pic_url, cat_name) {
    this.pic_url = pic_url;
    this.click_count = 0;
    this.cat_name = cat_name;
    return false;
}

var cat_name;
var pic_url;
var click_count;

function catClick() {
    var cat_click_p = document.getElementById("number_clicked");
    var number = cat_click_p.innerHTML;
    number  = parseInt(number) + 1;
    cat_click_p.innerHTML = number;
}

var catGrid = document.getElementById('cat_grid');
catGrid.addEventListener('click', catClick, false);
```

and the second version of the script, which does pass a string to the catClick function:

```
'use strict';

function CatCount (pic_url, cat_name) {
    this.pic_url = pic_url;
    this.click_count = 0;
    this.cat_name = cat_name;
    return false;
}

var cat_name;
var pic_url;
var click_count;

function catClick(element_id_to_be_replaced) {
    var cat_click_p = document.getElementById(element_id_to_be_replaced);
    var number = cat_click_p.innerHTML;
    number  = parseInt(number) + 1;
    cat_click_p.innerHTML = number;
}

var catGrid = document.getElementById('cat_grid');
catGrid.addEventListener('click', catClick('number_clicked'), false);
```

The second version of the script just increments the cat counter once.

Additionally, here is the `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/app.js'></script>

    <title>Cat App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        This app keeps track of how many times you click on a cat!
    <div class='cat' id='cat_grid'>
        <img src='http://thepetproductguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/CAT-HEADPHONES.jpeg'>
    </div>
    <div>
        This cat has been clicked
        <p id='number_clicked'>0</p>
        times.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line:

```
catGrid.addEventListener('click', catClick('number_clicked'), false);
```

In that line you are *executing* `catClick('number_clicked')` and returning the result of that expression as the 2nd parameter to the `addEventListener` function.

Two possible solutions are:

```
//1: Using an anonymous function:
catGrid.addEventListener('click', function() {
    catClick('number_clicked')
}, false);

//2: Using bind:
catGrid.addEventListener('click', catClick.bind(this,'number_clicked'), false);
```